# Error, problem in installing and running npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have problems installing npm and I can't run npm
When I type the following command, I get an error when I put the picture
`npm i`

```
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   38 more (@dhaiwat10/react-link-preview, @emoji-mart/react, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-instagram-embed
npm WARN   react-instagram-embed@"^1.5.0" from react-embed@3.6.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-embed
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-instagram-embed
npm WARN     react-instagram-embed@"^1.5.0" from react-embed@3.6.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-embed
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   16 more (@dhaiwat10/react-link-preview, @mui/base, @mui/lab, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-instagram-embed
npm WARN   react-instagram-embed@"^1.5.0" from react-embed@3.6.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-embed
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-instagram-embed
npm WARN     react-instagram-embed@"^1.5.0" from react-embed@3.6.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-embed

up to date, audited 1928 packages in 29s

128 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

131 vulnerabilities (1 low, 104 moderate, 22 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

When I type this code, I encounter the following problem`npm audit fix --force`

```
PS C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest> npm audit fix --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm WARN audit Updating react-scripts to 5.0.1, which is a SemVer major change.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @dhaiwat10/react-link-preview@1.15.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@dhaiwat10/react-link-preview
npm WARN     @dhaiwat10/react-link-preview@"^1.15.0" from the root project
npm WARN   39 more (@emoji-mart/react, @emotion/react, @emotion/styled, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-instagram-embed
npm WARN   react-instagram-embed@"^1.5.0" from react-embed@3.6.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-embed
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-instagram-embed
npm WARN     react-instagram-embed@"^1.5.0" from react-embed@3.6.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-embed
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN Found: react-dom@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @dhaiwat10/react-link-preview@1.15.0
npm WARN   node_modules/@dhaiwat10/react-link-preview
npm WARN     @dhaiwat10/react-link-preview@"^1.15.0" from the root project
npm WARN   16 more (@mui/base, @mui/lab, @mui/material, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react-dom@"^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-instagram-embed
npm WARN   react-instagram-embed@"^1.5.0" from react-embed@3.6.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-embed
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react-dom@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
npm WARN   peer react-dom@"^16.0.0 || ^15.0.0 || ~0.14.0" from react-instagram-embed@1.5.0
npm WARN   node_modules/react-instagram-embed
npm WARN     react-instagram-embed@"^1.5.0" from react-embed@3.6.0
npm WARN     node_modules/react-embed
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm WARN deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm WARN deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0

added 545 packages, removed 772 packages, changed 365 packages, and audited 1701 packages in 4m

264 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

# npm audit report

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          Depends on vulnerable versions of resolve-url-loader
          node_modules/react-scripts

postcss  <8.4.31
Severity: moderate
PostCSS line return parsing error - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7fh5-64p2-3v2j
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@3.0.1, which is a breaking change
node_modules/resolve-url-loader/node_modules/postcss
  resolve-url-loader  0.0.1-experiment-postcss || 3.0.0-alpha.1 - 4.0.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of postcss
  node_modules/resolve-url-loader

8 vulnerabilities (2 moderate, 6 high)

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

According to my research, these are not errors, but when I want to run npm, I encounter the following problem`npm run start`

```
PS C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest> npm run start

> c@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module './promise'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\bluebird.js
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\cacache\ls.js
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\cacache\locales\en.js
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\cacache\index.js
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\TaskRunner.js
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\terser-webpack-plugin\dist\cjs.js
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Abolfazl\Desktop\chat-app-latest\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\bluebird.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\bluebird\\js\\release\\bluebird.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\cacache\\lib\\entry-index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\cacache\\ls.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\cacache\\locales\\en.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\cacache\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\terser-webpack-plugin\\dist\\TaskRunner.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\terser-webpack-plugin\\dist\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\terser-webpack-plugin\\dist\\cjs.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\config\\webpack.config.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Abolfazl\\Desktop\\chat-app-latest\\node_modules\\react-scripts\\scripts\\start.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v20.10.0
```